# How can you pin the Penguin Suit Guy down?

Tags: building, storage, collectable-minifigures

I like penguins and so I was really amazed to find the [Penguin Suit Guy](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=147506#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) in Collectible Minifigures Series 16:

[image: Penguin Suit Guy standing up]

But despite coming with the [88646 tile](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=88646&idColor=11#T=C&C=11) he won't stick to it because of the skates:

[image: Penguin Suit Guy laying down]

There's no place to receive studs or anything else on the back of the legs.  So how can I keep the Penguin Suit Guy from bouncing around in his display case for ever more?  Is there a way to easily attach to the skates and not break too many LEGO best practices?

Comment: Whilst I wouldn't normally condone it, if he is going to be in the display case forever more, then glue may be a solution. Also, you have his right skate on backwards.

Comment: Instead of glue, a little bit of blu-tack will work also. This way, the attachment won't be permanent. OP could also just remove the skates and put them next to the stand. It's how most people display the penguin. There is also a possibility of angling the skates a bit to "hug" one of the studs on the plate. It's not a sturdy solution, but it allows the penguin to stand with the skates on.

Comment: Once I got the pictures in the computer I saw the reversed skate too.  I wish I could still see these things unaided, but my eyes are not as young as they once were.

Comment: Using glue would get me unglued grief from the lady in my life so that's not an option for me.  Blu-tack sounds like the easiest option, but I'm working on a brick-built solution.  I should be able to test it tonight or tomorrow.  If it works I'll definitely add an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was really stumped on this when I posted the question because there didn't seem to be any place to attach to.  But then I realized the neck could be a starting place.  I tried some things with hinges and plates, but decided to simplify and I ended up with:

[image: multicolor bricks]

With only 4 pieces I was able to get this to work out pretty nicely.  From neck to plate there are:

1. [42446](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=42446&idColor=11#T=C&C=11) "Minifig, Neck Bracket with Back Stud" - above in Brown
2. [30241](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=77988#T=C) "Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Clip Vertical" - above in Blue
3. [4599b](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4599b#T=C) the common Tap - the only Black part added above
4. [3005](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3005#T=C) Brick 1x1 - above in Lime

Looking at it from the front you can't see the additional parts much at all:

[image: front]

You can barely see some of the lime between his legs.  Switching to black bricks there's no chance of even that shining through:

[image]

I'm happy now that he won't be rattling around in his case forever.
And I hope folks are relieved to see his skates are going the right direction today.  I'm sure that made the skating easier until I pinned him down.  :-)

Comment: The neck bracket is available in black which makes it look even better

Answer (score 4):

For any CMF's with skates, I put the figure on the stand with no footwear, and attach the footwear to the holes behind their legs.  That way their accessories are there, and stuck to the figure, but the figure is on its stand!

Comment: That's a worthy idea, but it doesn't work in this case because their are no holes in the back of the legs.

Answer (score 1):

Spring-boarding off your nice work-around, I would suggest a further aesthetic tweak with the symmetrical re-positioning of the support shaft, and as a bonus, eliminating the 88646 tile all together, if it's not being used.

I don't have penguin accessories in my parts library, but here are some pics to help visualize my techno babble;)

[image]

[image]

While looking up the series, I noticed many of them come with the studs-down-the-middle 88646 tile, given that this is the standard baseplate for all of them, this work-around still mimics the same footprint this baseplate uses, and in conjunction with your tweak, pins down Penguin Suit mini-fig dead center.

R.I.P. Loki...

Comment: This is an interesting addition.  Thanks for the screen shots to make your plan clear.  Since the other minifigs all have the 88646 tile I'd like to keep that under the guy if possible for consistency.  With that tile the minifig will either be sitting on the studs or between them and I think between the studs looks better.